# Predict real value of new data points

Tags: python, machine-learning, interpolation

Suppose I have data points:

```
x = [(1, 2), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 7), (3, 1), (3, 5), (3, 6)] 
y = [2.3,5.6,9.0,8.6,4.2,13.5,11.0,1.3,5.0]
```

Now I want to predict the value of `y` for some new pairs, say `(2,3),(3,4)`
Suggest me a python code for the same.

I have tried with interpolation but couldn't get the result, I think some machine learning would do it, but I am really new in machine learning.
Suggest me a python code for the same.
Actual data I am working on is similar to these dummy data.[Want to predict values of missing point in the given image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTg1F.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. You need to provide all the details and 
mention the issue clearly what exactly you want. Please refer the
[ask] link for more detail and update your question accordingly.

Comment: I just to want know the value of y corresponding to point say-(2,3) on basis of the given training data set x and y.

Comment: you should start reading https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/

Comment: isn't there any machine learning tool to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use regression to predict. [scikit-learn-linear regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html)

I assume that you have enough data to apply machine learning. After train test split, you need to fit your train data to machine learning model in this case regression. You can do this by using `regression_model.fit(X_train,y_train)`

To be able to predict new points you can use `regression_model.predict(X)`
Do not forget to create your model object before trying these code. For more information [sklearn-linear_model.LinearRegression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html)

If you want to predict this particular point on this dataset, I suggest you to establish your model as y = ax1 + bx2 + error. You need to find coefficients  'a' and 'b' [linear_regression](http://www.statisticshowto.com/probability-and-statistics/regression-analysis/find-a-linear-regression-equation/)

Comment: Does the model "remember" what was fit, so model.predict(x) works afterwards?
Is the .predict(x) function the only thing needed after applying model training to get predictions?

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean by saying "remember" but when you fit, your regression model is ready to use and coefficients (a and b) are calculated according to your train set. In predict part, your model knows what a and b are, you give x1 and x2 rest of it is basic math. Hope this is helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

The previous comments are correct, one way is to use scikit-learn. All of its regression classes implement the same methods such that you can run a bunch of kinds of regressions as in the small example below (without train-test split):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression, Ridge, BayesianRidge
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, median_absolute_error

x = [(1, 2), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 7), (3, 1), (3, 5), (3, 6)] 
y = [2.3,5.6,9.0,8.6,4.2,13.5,11.0,1.3,5.0]

x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)

# collection of regression methods
models = {"OLS":LinearRegression(), 
          "R":Ridge(), 
          "BR":BayesianRidge()}

# collection of metrics for regression
metrics = {"mse":mean_squared_error,
           "mae":median_absolute_error}

# training
for m in sorted(models):
    print("\n",m)
    models[m].fit(x,y)
    # metrics for comparison of regression methods
    for me in sorted(metrics):
        print("metric",me,metrics[me](y, models[m].predict(x)))
```

**Edit:**

Prediction of new values can then be done via:

```
x_new = np.array([[2,3],
                  [3,4]])

for m in sorted(models):
    print("\n",m)
    print(models[m].predict(x_new))
```

BR
[ 6.7211654  6.7218773]

OLS
[ 6.28459643  6.67948244]

R
[ 6.29948927  6.66721144]

Comment: So this is the output of your code:('\n', 'BR')
('metric', 'mae', 2.5225241705097812)
('metric', 'mse', 14.720460545421929)
('\n', 'OLS')
('metric', 'mae', 2.6472581638940236)
('metric', 'mse', 14.454453344286987)
('\n', 'R')
('metric', 'mae', 2.6430030643513787)
('metric', 'mse', 14.454929989894472)

Comment: if data X=(3,4) value of y will a*3 + b*4 +error.so in this case what are the values of a,b and error.

Comment: @Eric-please give a reply on my comments.Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I've overlooked that, my bad. Edited the answer.